# Memory leak in libavcodec for Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2012, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm using libavcodec for [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and `avformat_open_input()` appears to have a significant memory leak.  If I open 5,000 videos, the OS reports 2 GB of RAM consumed that is not freed when the application exits.  Here is the code:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVDictionary *dict = NULL;
int result = 0;

av_register_all();

// open the input video file
IntPtr ip = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(videoFilename);
const char* filename = static_cast<const char*>(ip.ToPointer());
result = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, &dict);
if (result < 0) {
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ip);
    return result;
}

Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ip);
avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
return result;
```

The above code is in a class library that is called from C#.  I'm using managed C++ to call the libavcodec libraries.  The flow is C# -> Managed C++ -> libavcodec.  I'm using DLL's and dynamic linking.  This is a single threaded application.  When I use threads, as expected, the leak increases.

I've tried the following:

- I've tried a couple of the 32-bit builds and the memory leak is consistent.
- Using `NULL` instead of `&dict`.
- Calling `avformat_open_input()` with the *same* file name 5,000+ times which does *not* leak memory.
- Using combinations `avformat_alloc_context()` and `avformat_free_context()`.  I can't find a combination that frees memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting back to this in case someone finds this useful.

As it turns out, if I just open and close a file, there is a memory leak.  However, if I do functions like (read, seek, etc.), there isn't a memory leak.